# pip.install has stopped working: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package>"

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have seen a few related questions, and I've tried all of their recommendations:

- I'm using anaconda, so I downgraded from 3.7 to 3.6
- I upgraded pip using curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python
- I installed the latest version of openssl (1.1.1)
- I updated all Anaconda libraries
- I am connected to the Internet (obviously, since I'm posting here) and not behind a firewall.

And yet, every time I run "pip install " or "pip install ==" I get the following error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement  (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for

I'm on a Mac, Mojave v10.14.4

I recently installed prodigy.ai, which seemed to replace a bunch of packages with (perhaps) older versions, but I still cannot figure out how to fix this issue.  The one thing I haven't tried is uninstalling Anaconda and reinstalling it.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Sorry -- when I run "pip install package" or "pip install package=version"...

Comment: I tried de-installing and re-installing Anaconda... no joy.

Comment: What do `python --version` and `pip --version` output?

Comment: (base) Jeffs-MacBook-Pro-2:RDC jeffsidell$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
(base) Jeffs-MacBook-Pro-2:RDC jeffsidell$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /Users/jeffsidell/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Comment: So: Python 3.7.3 and pip 19.0.3

Comment: Ok, so these two match; can you give an example of package not being installed? E.g. if you issue `pip install --force-reinstall wheel`, will the command succeed?

Comment: That command succeeds.  Here's one that fails:

Comment: (base) Jeffs-MacBook-Pro-2:RDC jeffsidell$ pip install psycopg
Collecting psycopg
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for psycopg

Comment: You probably mean `psycopg2`. `psycopg` doesn't contain a release to install and is obsolete anyway.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed... pip install psycopg2 works... argh.

Comment: No worries, that's part of the learning curve. happened to me lots of times ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it happened to me also.

A common case in this procedure is to check if you have not made a **typo** when entering the **package name**.